# How to differentiate if a Cisco device is a L3 switch or a Router?

Tags: cisco, switch, router

I need to check all the L3 switches if they are configured with same ospf ID,
As i am doing it in the Cisco prime, there are routers in the inventory too.
Is there a show command where i can clearly distinguish between a router and a switch.

Comment: OSPF ID is supposed to be unique on each device running ospf.  The command “show ip ospf” will show the ospf id or if the ospf process is not running on the device. If the device does not support ospf the “show ip ospf” command will not be recognized.

Comment: FYI ospf area is completely different than ospf id.  OSPF process ID is also something different.  “Show ip ospf” also shows the ospf process ID.  Very informative command.

Comment: If any of the answers have solved your problem, please don't forget to vote accordingly and mark a solution as accepted so this question doesn't continue to come up as unresolved.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin I didn't find any answers helpful, there is more to it than just executing `show version`.

Comment: OK, that's fine. I was doing some year-end cleanup. If you figured it out, you can post and accept your own answer, too.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `show inventory` since that will show Model (also known as PID), version (hardware revision) ID, along with the serial number.  For a switch it would show something like `PID: WS-C3850-48T-E, VID: V02, SN: FOC1234567` so you know right away that it's a switch, model Catalyst 3850 48-port.

Answer (score 2):

Use below command. You can identify

```
Show Version
```

Comment: Can you add more info about your answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use

`#show version`

This command displays details status of device includes  hardware , iOS version , model , uptime .

Difference in operation from layer3 Switch and router

**In router**

Nat configuration can be done in router. Which is not feasible in layer3 switch .